# GraalVM Tracing Agent Not Generating Configs

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I followed the instructions [https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/] and ran my app with a command of the form:

```
sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=/home/temp/ -jar app.jar
```

I interacted with the app, but after closing it, the /temp directory remained empty of any json config files.

Also, why do I need to run this command using sudo rights? If I drop the sudo then I get:

```
native-image-agent: Error: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/temp
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: native-image-agent
```

And it seems a devil at holding locks on the specified directory:

```
native-image-agent: Error: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/temp/.lock
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: native-image-agent
```

and locks to pids that don't exist:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=/home/temp/ -m app.Main
native-image-agent: Error: Output directory '/home/temp' is locked by process 6451, which means another agent instance is already writing to this directory. Only one agent instance can safely write to a specific target directory at the same time. Unless file '.lock' is a leftover from an earlier process that terminated abruptly, it is unsafe to delete it. For running multiple processes with agents at the same time to create a single configuration, read AutomaticMetadataCollection.md or https://www.graalvm.org/dev/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/ on how to use the native-image-configure tool.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: native-image-agent
```

```
$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   6100 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
   6478 pts/0    00:00:00 ps


$ kill 6451 -pid
bash: kill: (6451) - No such process
bash: kill: -pid: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

My $JAVA_HOME is: /home/graalvm/graalvm-jdk-17.0.7+8.1

Comment: Apparently you don't have permissions to write to `/home/temp`. Just choose another directory

Comment: I'm the sole user and creator of /temp.

Comment: Here's what I have on both Linux/Mac [drwxr-xr-x    2 apple  staff     64 27 Jul 13:11 temp] showing the first 3 owner permissions are r/w/x, so I as the owner of /temp do have all 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue but no different user paths involved, but returning the same issue. I'd say you have an actual permissions issue, but the lock is suspicious, so let's expose my case as another scenario where the same issue gets triggered.

Make sure you are not doing some custom java fork/launch from your code itself, I was using something like this to bypass a restriction by running the jar from the jar with add-exports, so you need to add them to the command line by hand to skip the nested run. Here's how my code doing this:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        for (String s : args) {
            if (s.equals("run")) {
                doMain(args);
                return;
            }
        }
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        String processCommand = ProcessHandle.current().info().command().orElse("java");
        command.add(processCommand);
        String[] arguments = ProcessHandle.current().info().arguments().orElse(new String[0]);
        if (arguments.length == 0) {
            command.add("-jar");
            command.add(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        }
        command.add("--add-exports");
        command.add("jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper=ALL-UNNAMED");
        for (String argument : arguments) command.add(argument);
        command.add("run");
        new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(command).start().waitFor();
    }

    public static void doMain(String[] args) {
        // Real main
    }
```

So in my case I used something to `java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=/your/path -jar fat.jar run` where `run` was the magic word to prevent adding the `-jar [itself]` arg, and that worked for me.